# I am unable to convert a custom cell format of ##\:## to time

Tags: excel

I am currently trying to convert a custom cell format of ##:## to time, either military time or AM/PM.  When trying a simple conversion in format cells it comes back with "0:00 or 12:00 AM".  I have tried separating and putting it back together as time and that is not working either.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: format does not change the underlying value.  To change in place will require vba.  A formula can do this but in a different cell.

Answer (score 0):

format does not change the underlying value. To change in place will require vba. A formula can do this but in a different cell.

For formula use:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"##\:##")
```

Then format the result cell as `HH:MM`

For VBA:

```
Sub timechange()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = CDate(Format(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), "##\:##"))
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
End Sub
```